# Unity 2D - Why Rect.Contains does Not work in this example?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rect

In a 2D space:
I have an sprite and a script component is assigned to it
I've this statement in the Start method:
"onScreenRect = rt.rect;"
It will Not detect mouseOver as it could be expected!
Now if this statement is moved to Update method, it will.
Please explain why.

```
public class EvtPub : MonoBehaviour
{
  RectTransform rt;
  Rect onScreenRect;
  void Start()
  {
    rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    // having next statement here, the code will Not work!
    onScreenRect = rt.rect;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    // having next statement here, the code Will work!
    // onScreenRect = rt.rect;
    onScreenRect.Set(onScreenRect.x + transform.position.x, 
      onScreenRect.y + transform.position.y, onScreenRect.width, onScreenRect.height);
    if (onScreenRect.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
    {
      Debug.Log("Mouse over detected!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, Rect in Unity is a struct,it's a value type. which means the onScreenRect will be a value copy of the rt.Rect,not the reference. when you put the statement in Start(), the value will be copied only one time and will not be updated. :)sry about my poor English and  hope helpful.